# How to append a <li> as the first list item in a <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a html page (index.html) which calls the ajax page(aj.php). The Ajax page will return some number of `<li>`'s, like

```
<li>Blue Flower</li>
<li>White Assassin</li>
```

I already have some list items in the `<ul>` of the html page(index.html). When i try to append the result of the ajax page i.e.,`<li>`'s,  it is appending at the last.

I want the `<li>`'s which returned from ajax page should be at first. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to have the items at first, its [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), not append :-)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the `.prependTo()` function of jQuery? Docs are [here](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).

So it'd be something like:

```
var returnedLIs = fromPHP;
$(returnedLIs).prependTo($('your ul'));
```